# Regular Expression for different api url and renaming the resultant events in splunk

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to get the event count for below api in splunk for that I am trying to write regular expression for api but its not selecting hypen not sure how to write the regular expression to extract field out of it

```
"GET /v1/resource-plans/store-manager-view?type=
"GET /v1/resource-plans/trend ? xyz=
"GET /v1/resource-plans/store-director-view ? location =
"POST /v1/resource-plans
```

I have tried below expression its selecting store-manager and store-director into one but i need count for all api different row

```
(?<TYPE>\/v1\/resource-plans\/\w+)
```

[image]

And also i want to **rename the resultant events** defined in field column TYPE how to do this ? Below is my Splunk query

```
  index=msc AND app=xyz AND source=resouce NOT message="*/_status" | rex field= message "(?<TYPE>\/v1\/resource-plans\/\w+)
    " | stats count by TYPE
```

Comment: Adding hyphen is easy - `(?<TYPE>/v1/resource-plans/[\w-]+)` or `(?<TYPE>/v1/resource-plans/[^/?#]+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but its not selecting "POST /v1/resource-plans rest all three are selecting

Comment: It is due to the missing part after `resource-plans`, [see](https://regex101.com/r/PbSllR/1) `(?<TYPE>/v1/resource-plans(?:/[^/?#]+)?)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any idea how rename the results of TYPE instead of showing whole url

Comment: You can use a lookup table to translate the TYPE event text to different text.  Or you could just use an eval with a case inside.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the regex part, you can use

```js
(?<TYPE>/v1/resource-plans(?:/[^/?#]+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PbSllR/1). *Details*:

- `/v1/resource-plans` - a literal fixed string
- `(?:/[^/?#]+)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `/` - a slash
  - `[^/?#]+` - one or more chars other than `/`, `?` and `#`